# Combination lab

Tags: javascript, html

The first text box you are going to enter the your full name. For example, Michael Chu

In the second text box you are going to enter your full address: For example,  3141 Chestnut Street, Philadelphia, PA 19104

Once you click on the submit button:

It will display the following in the third text box (last name first, comma, space, and first name)

Chu, Michael

It will display the following in the fourth text box (First character of the first name, first character of the last name, and last 4 character from the address box)

MC9104

I have this so far:

```
   var FullName = document.forms["Validate"]["FullName"].value;

    if (FullName == "") {

    alert("Please enter a Full Name");

    return false;
    }
var space = FullName.indexOf(" ");

var LastName = FullName.substring(Space+1);

var FirstName = FullName.substring(0, Space);

FirstName+LastName;


var Char1 = FirstName.charAt(0);
var Char2 = LastName.charAt(0);
var AddressSplit=Address.length-4;
var finalAddress=address.substring(addressSplit);

concat(Char1,Char2,finalAddress);
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a homework problem and that you are wanting someone to write the code for you (I do hope neither of these are true....)

However, the task clearly states that a TEXT BOX (which is the right way to enter data in an HTML file) should be used - so why are you using an ALERT???

Read up on HTML INPUT - it should look something like

```
<input type="text" name="fullname" />
```

Each of the inputs will be similar.

Also you will need to read about FORMS, as the task says to do something after a submit button.  A form has input boxes in it, so something like...

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="fullname" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

now, that is just a basic start - there is a LOT more that you need to do for this to work - including the javascript to update additional boxes, etc.......

If this is a homework problem, it sounds like you didn't pay much attention in class....

Comment: The biggest problem with your answer is that you answered. Do not answer off topic questions which are unclear and make you guess at what he wants. It wastes everyone's time, especially yours when this gets closed.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Answer (score -2):

i hope this help you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
      <script language="JavaScript">
    function getdata(){
      var fullname = document.getElementById("fullname").value;
      var address= document.getElementById("address").value;
      var arrname=fullname.split(" ");
      var pos=fullname.search(" ");
      document.getElementById('result1').value = arrname[1]+'. '+arrname[0] ;
      document.getElementById('result2').value = fullname[0]+fullname.slice(pos+1,pos+2)+address.slice(-4,address.length) ;
          }
    </script>

    <div class="input">
    <textarea id = "fullname" rows = "6" cols = "80">
    </textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="input">
    <textarea id = "address" rows = "6" cols = "80">
    </textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="push">
    <button onclick="getdata()">Get</button>
    </div>

    <div class="result">
    <textarea id = "result1" rows = "6" cols = "80">
    </textarea>
    </div>
    
    <div class="result">
    <textarea id = "result2" rows = "6" cols = "80">
    </textarea>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer But no question was ever asked so how can you possibly give an answer at all?

Comment: no question ever asked in question section? so you explain what is this?@rob

Comment: The poster has not asked a question or stated what his problem is. The "question" is up for closure.